# Convert an array to dictionary with value as index of the item and key as the item itself

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have an array such as -

```
arr[0] = "Name";
arr[1] = "Address";
arr[2] = "Phone";
...
```

I want to create a `Dictionary<string, int>` such that the array values will be the dictionary keys and the dictionary values will be the index, so that I can get the index of a column by querying its name in `O(1)`. I know this should be fairly simple, but I can't get my head around it.

I tried -

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDict = arr.ToDictionary(x => x, x => indexOf(x))
```

however, this returns -

```
{(Name, 0), (Address, 0), (Phone, 0),...}
```

I know this happens because it is storing the index of the first occurence, but that's not what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Sorry, but why would you need that either way?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use the overload of `Select` which includes the index:

```
var dictionary = array.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                      .ToDictionary(pair => pair.value, pair => pair.index);
```

Or use `Enumerable.Range`:

```
var dictionary = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length).ToDictionary(x => array[x]);
```

Note that `ToDictionary` will throw an exception if you try to provide two equal keys. You should think carefully about the possibility of your array having two equal values in it, and what you want to happen in that situation.

I'd be tempted just to do it manually though:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    dictionary[array[i]] = i;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the first two will error out if there are duplicate values.  They might want to add a `Distinct` first.

Comment: @Servy: I'll add a note, but without a suggested solution other than "you need to consider this" :)

Comment: The 1st option worked like a charm, the 2nd gave an error on array[i](couldn't find i)

Comment: @neuDev33 the 2nd has a typo. It should be like this: `Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length).ToDictionary(x => array[x], x => x);`

Comment: @JonSkeet Out of the 3 methods you mentioned, which one is the most time efficient? Will this depend on the data size?

Comment: The last option is probably the most efficient - but I wouldn't expect any of them to have different underlying complexity, if you see what I mean. So I'd probably go for whatever you find the most readable until you have a reason not to.

Comment: ```x => x``` can be omitted in the second one :
```var dictionary2 = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length).ToDictionary(x => arr[x]);
```

Comment: The one with the Enumerable.Range is the fastest. On my system, with a list of one million items, I get 60ms with the Select-indexer, 32 ms with the Enumerable.Range, and 38ms with the For-loop.

Comment: @hcd: These days, I'd probably do that with a value tuple, which might change things.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is:

```
var dictionary = arr.ToDictionary(x => Array.IndexOf(arr, x));
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some benchmarks, because in my scenario performance and allocations were important. Here is what I finally used:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<T, int>(array.Length);
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    dictionary[array[i]] = i;
```

The trick is to set initial capacity to reduce reallocations inside dictionary data structures. See following table to compare result (less is better, baseline was set to @Jon Skeet first answer):

| Method | Ratio | Alloc Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Preallocate | 0.29 | 0.27 |
| Manual for loop | 0.48 | 0.73 |
| Enumerable.Range | 0.63 | 0.78 |
| Select(Tuple) | 1.0 | 0.78 |
| Select(Anonymous type) | 1.0 | 1.0 |