# C# List<object> to Dictionary<key, <object>>

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I am a beginner c# developer and I need to create a dictionary of object from my list. First, let me define my object as Person.

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a list of my person object. `List<Person>`
How to query it in LinQ to convert it to a Dictionary of Person from my list?
My desired output is:

```
Dictionary<key, <Person>>
```

Where key is an incrementing integer per Person object..
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

I found this code online but it works with `List<string>`

```
List<string> List1
var toDict = List1.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
             .ToDictionary(x => x.i, x => x.s)
```

Comment: What are the `keys` here? Name? Id?

Comment: Do you want the key be exactly new integer or the same as your `Person.Id` propery?

Comment: May I know what's reason of creating dictionary with just a number as key? What are you trying to do and why?

Comment: @Seprum `key is an incrementing integer per Person object`

Comment: @Ian I need the key to be an exactly new integer

Comment: @Saleem I need the key to be an exactly new integer

Comment: Well, in that case just loop through your list and add items to dictionary based on it's index.

Comment: @Saleem i will be using the dictionary in a infinite scroll method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert an array to dictionary with value as index of the item and key as the item itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252225/convert-an-array-to-dictionary-with-value-as-index-of-the-item-and-key-as-the-it)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

One most straight forward way would be to use the `int key` as `key` like this:

```
List<Person> List1 = new List<Person>();
int key = 0; //define this for giving new key everytime
var toDict = List1.Select(p => new { id = key++, person = p })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x.person);
```

The key is the lambda expression:

```
p => new { id = key++, person = p }
```

Where you create an anonymous `object` having `id` and `person` properties. The `id` is incremental `key` while the `person` is simply the element of your `List<Person>`

If you need to use the `Person`'s Id instead, simply use:

```
List<Person> List1 = new List<Person>();
var toDict = List1.Select(p => new { id = p.Id, person = p })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x.person);
```

Comment: Thank you for a very complete newbie-friendly answer. I will select this as the answer later when I can (answered too fast 5 more min)

Comment: @super-user no problem. :) it may take some times to learn. But hope you get it - I purposely put up some explanations for you to understand how the Lambda expression in the example you found work.

Comment: @super-user as for more efficient way of doing that without going from your example, kindly check Seprum's answer.

Comment: the last ".Select" statment has an extra "(", which should be removed.

Answer (score 15):

This should work for your case:

```
int key = 0; // Set your initial key value here.
var dictionary = persons.ToDictionary(p => key++);
```

Where `persons` is `List<Person>`.

Comment: You could easily win code golf challenge with this. +1

Comment: Thank you! Neat and short. +1 Sorry minute too late to be selected as the answer

Comment: @super-user: [whispers] You can always change your accepted answer. :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120568/is-it-possible-to-change-the-chosen-answer

Answer (score 4):

You were almost there, just change variable type from `List<string>` to `List<Person>` and you are good to go. You can use your LINQ query as is, example:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

var p1 = new Person();
p1.Name = "John";
persons.Add(p1);

var p2 = new Person();
p2.Name = "Mary";
persons.Add(p2);

var toDict = persons.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
             .ToDictionary(x => x.i, x => x.s);
```

However, while I don't have anything against LINQ, in this particular case a much more readable approach is using a regular loop like this:

```
var result = new Dictionary<int, Person>();
for (int i = 0; i < persons.Count; i++)
{
    result.Add(i, persons[i]);
}
```

[Jon Skeet suggests yet another way of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252272/897326), using `Enumerable.Range`, which I tested and it works perfectly:

```
var toDict = Enumerable.Range(0, persons.Count)
             .ToDictionary(x => x, x => persons[x]);
```

Comment: thanks! works too, I appreciate the suggestions, will look into it. + 1

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
var key = 0;
IDictionary<int, Person> personDictionary = personList
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int,Person>(key++, x))
    .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, y => y.Value);
```

where `personList` is `List<Person>`