# Selecting List<string> into Dictionary with index

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a List

```
List<string> sList = new List<string>() { "a","b","c"};
```

And currently I am selecting this into a dictionary the following structure:

```
//(1,a)(2,b)(3,c)
Dictionary<int, string> dResult = new Dictionary<int, string>();
for(int i=0;i< sList.Count;i++)
{
    dResult.Add(i, sList[i]);
}
```

but with Linq I've seen some slimmer way like `ToDictionary((x,index) =>`

How is the correct syntax or how can this be solved within one line?

Comment: You *are* aware that the original list will be more performant than the dictionary? I.e. a dictionary is usually used when you have sparse or non-numerical keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert an array to dictionary with value as index of the item and key as the item itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252225/convert-an-array-to-dictionary-with-value-as-index-of-the-item-and-key-as-the-it)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the overload of `Select` that projects the index to fill an anonymous type:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dResult = sList
    .Select((s, index) => new { s, index })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.index, x => x.s);
```

That is the same as what your code does. If you instead want the result you've commented: `(1,a)(2,b)(3,c)`) you have to add +1 so `ToDictionary(x => x.index+1, x => x.s)`.

Answer (score 12):

There's no `ToDictionary` method that gives this in a single call, as there are no overloads that provide the index, but you can use the `Select` overload which accepts a `Func<T, int, TResult>`:

```
var dictionary = list.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                     .ToDictionary(pair => pair.index, pair => pair.value);
```

Or in C# 7, avoiding creating a bunch of heap-allocated objects using `ValueTuple`:

```
var dictionary = list.Select((v, i) => (value: v, index: i))
                     .ToDictionary(pair => pair.index, pair => pair.value);
```

As of C# 7.1 point release, you can use the inferred `ValueTuple` literal expression:

```
var dictionary = list.Select((value, index) => (value, index))
                     .ToDictionary(pair => pair.index, pair => pair.value);
```

(As noted by Tim, you'll need to adjust the index by 1 to get the original requested output.)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this approach without an anonymous type:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dResult = Enumerable
    .Range(0, sList.Count())
    .ToDictionary(i => i + 1, i => sList[i]);
```

Answer (score 3):

First you have to get the key and value using the [select-overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) that also provices the index of the currently used element:

```
var tmp = sList.Select((x, i) => new { Key = i, Value = x });
```

Now create the dictionary:

```
var result = tmp.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
var result = sList.Select((x, i) => new { Key = i, Value = x }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

EDIT: You can also create your own extension-method to also use the syntax you provided:

```
public static Dictionary<TResultKey, TResultValue> ToDictionary<TSource, TResultKey, TResultValue>(this IEnumerable<TSource> src, Func<TSource, int, TResultKey> KeySelector, Func<TSource, int, TResultValue> ValueSelector) 
{
    var result = new Dictionary<TResultKey, TResultValue>();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var element in src)
    {
        result[KeySelector(element, i)]  = ValueSelector(element, i);
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
List<string> sList = new List<string>() { "a","b","c"};
var result = sList.ToDictionary((x, i) => i + 1, (x, i) => x);
```