# Sorting an IOrderedEnumerable into an arbitrary order

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<string,var>>` (value in the `IGrouping` not relevant to the question, so abstracted with var). I have a `List<string>` that contains the strings used as the keys for the `IGrouping`. I want to be able to re-order the `IOrderedEnumerable` by key, so that the `IGrouping`s are held in the same order as the `List`.

I've had a look at `IOrderedEnumerable.OrderBy(v => v.Key)`, but that only seems to do ascending order - I can't see a way to bully that into using a list as a reference. I presume the trick is to write a key selector that could do it, but my LINQ-fu isn't strong enough.

Comment: Is this meant to be a `ThenBy` that only changes same-order elements within the `IOrderedEnumerable` or is the fact that it's an `IOrderedEnumerable` irrelevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iOrderedEnumerable.OrderBy(v => thatListOfString.IndexOf(v.Key))
```

If you want to avoid searching through the list again for each `v`, you can [cache the positions in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15252225/11683):

```
var cached_positions = thatListOfString
                          .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                          .ToDictionary(pair => pair.value, pair => pair.index);

iOrderedEnumerable.OrderBy(v => cached_positions[v.Key])
```

Comment: this seems to be very inefficient though for large set of data.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary premature optimization? :) On the other hand source can have 10 entries and code will be executed once a week. Though I'm always OK with better solutions if any. And vote them too

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
thatListOfString
  .Select((orderIndex, stringValue)=>new{orderIndex, stringValue})
  .Join(
    orderedGroups,
    left=>left.stringValue,
    right=>right.Key,
    (left,right)=>new{left,right}
  )
  .OrderBy(lr=>lr.left.orderIndex)//actually with current internal implementation of Enumerable.Join this one is not needed
  .Select(lr=>lr.right);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> orderStrings = new List<string>() { "b", "a", "z" };

            List<List<object>> data = new List<List<object>>() {
                new List<object> {"a", 1},
                new List<object> {"a", 2},
                new List<object> {"a", 3},
                new List<object> {"a", 4},
                new List<object> {"b", 5},
                new List<object> {"b", 6},
                new List<object> {"b", 7},
                new List<object> {"z", 8},
                new List<object> {"z", 9},
            };

            var results = data.GroupBy(x => x[0]).OrderBy(x => orderStrings.IndexOf((string)x.Key)).ToList();

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: That does not seem to add anything to the existing answers.

Comment: Your answer uses a dictionary and mine doesn't.  Also my solution is much simpler than your code.

Comment: Your answer is the first line of my answer. Then in my answer I also show how to use a dictionary for speed.

Comment: Would the person posting know that?  My code runs and gives a real answer, does yours?

Comment: Would the person posting know that 95% of your answer is just setting up a test case, that the actual meaningful part of your answer is `OrderBy(x => orderStrings.IndexOf((string)x.Key))` and that it is identical to the already posted `iOrderedEnumerable.OrderBy(v => thatListOfString.IndexOf(v.Key))`? I hope they would, and I hope you either delete your answer or add something new to it, otherwise it creates noise and unnecessarily spreads the readers attention.

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes.  You should be the one to delete your answer that is in complete.

Comment: I did indeed work out (after a minute or two of staring at it) that most of this answer was irrelevant setting up of a test case, and that the actual answer was a single line identical to the already provided answer.