# Choosing text file to use as dictionary in Unity

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game where the user selects a category before playing the game. Depending on the category selected the necessary dictionary is loaded here is the code for doing that

```
public Text selectedCategory; //contains the text of the selected category
private Dictionary<String,String> wordList = new Dictionary<String,String> (); //holds the dictionary
private string[] wordListArray; //the array the contents of the text file is first loaded to
private TextAsset textAsset; //the text asset to be used
private string category; // the category selected

void Awake(){
    category = selectedCategory.text;
    textAsset = Resources.Load ("words", typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;
    Debug.Log ("Words dictionary is loaded");
    wordListArray = textAsset.text.Split (new char[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    wordList = wordListArray.ToDictionary (s => s);
    Debug.Log ("File loaded as dictionary");
}
```

This first piece of code works perfectly but when i change it to

```
void Awake(){
    category = selectedCategory.text;
    if (String.Compare(category, "Animals") == 1) {
        textAsset = Resources.Load ("animals", typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;
        Debug.Log ("Animals dictionary is loaded");
    } else {
        textAsset = Resources.Load ("words", typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;
        Debug.Log ("Words dictionary is loaded");
    }
    wordListArray = textAsset.text.Split (new char[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    wordList = wordListArray.ToDictionary (s => s);
    Debug.Log ("File loaded as dictionary");
}
```

I get the error code

> ArgumentException: An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary.
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String].Add (System.String key, System.String value) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:404)
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[String,String,String] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 keySelector, System.Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[String,String] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[String,String] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 keySelector)
>   GameController.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/GameController.cs:127)

Comment: Doesn't look like your code came through in your question?

Comment: @Abdul Thanks I had the same problem, your question helped me in finding a solution

Comment: @Thematkinson i have edited it... Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C# Dictionary has a key-value structure, meaning it looks something like this:

`Dictionary<string, string> dictionary` example:

```
(Key => Value)

"greeting" => "Hello"
"animal" => "Dog"
```

And when getting a value you give the dictionary the string `Key` and it returns the value.

```
 Debug.Log(dictionary["greeting"]) --> "Hello"
```

So when you, in your text file, tries to add multiple Keys of the same value, for instance:

```
"greeting" => "Hello"
"animal" => "Dog"
"greeting" => "Hey"
```

You will get an exception, because you're breaking how the Dictionary works (one unique key for a value). If you didn't get an exception and you'd try to access the value of the key "greeting", which value would you get?

```
Debug.Log(dictionary["greeting"]) --> ???
```

Which is why you get an exception at compilation.

You need to make sure every key is unique. In your text file you have multiple instances of the same word. I don't see the use of a Dictionary, perhaps you're stuck on the semantics of the word "Dictionary" and what you wish to use it for. I think a List is what you're after(?), meaning no Keys, only values.

Since I don't know what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to recommend a solution but you can read more on Dictionary [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252225/convert-an-array-to-dictionary-with-value-as-index-of-the-item-and-key-as-the-it)'s an answer to how you populate it from an array if you actually need it to be a dictionary.

---

Update:

> I used a dictionary because I want to be able to check if the text file contains a word

Ok! I think a Dictionary is not what you want; it's a List you're after. Add all the words to a List:

```
wordList = wordListArray.ToList();
```

and the check if the list contains the word you want to check (can be done on your array as well)

```
if (wordList.contains(YourString)) {
    Debug.Log(YourString + " exist in wordList!");
}
```

---

Update2:

> I get the structure of the dictionary but from my code I am loading the contents of the text file into the dictionary and before doing that depending on the category selected a particular text file is loaded... say i have text files with names animals, countries, names. if the person selects names the names text file is loaded

Gives me the impression that you have another issue, namely how to select which file to load. Well for this you need something to vary on, which I will assume you have, let's call it `playerChoice`. Here's how you could do it:

```
TextAsset textAsset;
switch (playerChoice) {
    case "PlayerOption1":
        textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("words1", typeof(TextAsset));
    break;
    case "PlayerOption2":
        textAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("words2", typeof(TextAsset));
    break;
}

// and then the rest of your textAsset, 
// handling code (splitting on linebreaks and .ToList())
```

Since I don't know when you want to load a different file this is as low abstraction I could make.

Comment: I used a dictionary because I want to be able to check if the text file contains a word

Comment: Nailed it @Fredrik. +1

Comment: @Abdul Ok! I updated the answer, check the bottom! Mr.Biggleworth, thank you! =)

Comment: I get the structure of the dictionary but from my code I am loading the contents of the text file into the dictionary and before doing that depending on the category selected a particular text file is loaded... say i have  text files with names animals, countries, names. if the person selects names the names text file is loaded

Comment: So your question is also how to decide which file to choose? Or do you just have 1 text file but with different kinds of content in it, that you wish to separate and load?

Comment: the question is chosing which file to load @Fredrik... but I'd be glad if I had an insight to your second suggestion

Comment: I updated the answer again! Check and see if that answers your question!

Comment: Yh Thank you very much everything works perfectly now... Combining your initial suggestion of using a List and and then applying the switch to it.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bit of confusion around the logic here. You seem to be trying to decide which text document to load with textAsset variable but then you seem to load all of the text from the file and then stick it in a dictionary.

If you have different text files with unique content then just have a list of enums and let the player choose one. Then load a different text file based on their decision.

```
enum Days {Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

Then in your code have something like:

```
var currentChoice; //Value set elsewhere in code (through UI)
textAsset = Resources.Load (currentChoice.ToString(), typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;
```

Then you get the right assets based on their choice.

Comment: Yeah, this is cleaner than my suggestion. +1 right back to ya buddy

Comment: Thanks buddy, long may the Stack Overflow love fest continue.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the answers given by @Fredrik here is the full working code

```
public Text selectedCategory; //contains the text of the selected category
private List<String> wordList; //holds the dictionary
private string[] wordListArray; //the array the contents of the text file is first loaded to
private TextAsset textAsset; //the text asset to be used
private string category; // the category selected

//new function to load the dictionary
void LoadDictionary(string category){
    switch (category) {
    case "Animals":
        textAsset = Resources.Load ("animals", typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;
        Debug.Log ("Animals dictionary is loaded");
        break;
    default:
        textAsset = Resources.Load ("words", typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;
        Debug.Log ("Words dictionary is loaded");
        break;
    }
    wordListArray = textAsset.text.Split (new char[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    wordList = wordListArray.ToList();
    Debug.Log ("File is loaded");
}
```

This function is called in the start function as follows

```
void Start () {
    selectedCategory.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("categorySelected");
    category = selectedCategory.text;
    LoadDictionary (category);
}
```